# Duvida banco MySQL

Tags: mysql

Nesse banco de dados e não estou conseguindo fazer:

Tenho isso:

```
 value_id | entity_type_id | attribute_id | entity_id | value
 600      | 2              | 22           | 40        | Gaga
 601      | 2              | 20           | 40        | Tonha
```

e gostaria de transformar nisso

```
 value_id | entity_type_id | attribute_id | entity_id | value1  | value2
          |                |              |           | Gaga    | Tonha
```

O restante dos campos que estão em branco, para mim não importa ou não

Answer (score 0):

Para adicionar a coluna value2 na tabela :

```
ALTER TABLE suatabela ADD value2 varchar(255)
```

Feito isso voce pode inserir seus dados desse modo:
Ex:

```
INSERT INTO suatabela VALUES(600,2,22,40,'Gaga','Tonha');
```